# Transfer folders and files from Linux to Winows using SCP as protocol in WinSCP.com (command line utility)

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, scp, winscp

I have to login onto a remote Linux target using a local windows machine. I was using Putty and WinSCP as a GUI utilities to login. But I have a requirement which needs to automate the login procedure and transfer files/folders. As the host system runs Windows, the normal SCP command is not working for me. But GUI WinSCP.exe runs good but only after selecting SCP as protocol, as SFTP and FTP doesn't work. Now in order to automate the login, I need to use WinSCP.com or command line for WinSCP which uses SCP. I tried using WinSCP.com and selected SFTP as protocol, but its not working. The connection is cutoff immediately. 
What is the procedure/syntax to logon to the target.

Comment: "... the normal SCP command is not working for me." Why not?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: As in Windows command prompt SCP command shows as unrecognised command.

Comment: Have you tried installing it?

Comment: In Windows, Naah!!! It was better to install WinSCP and use it. WinSCP itself is using SCP protocol with Putty integration (which uses PSCP, as to my knowledge).

Comment: Clearly it is not, since it is not suitable for your purposes.

Comment: WinSCP GUI might be using SCP service in background, It already has support to use SFTP in command line, but I wanted to use SCP feature from command line as for GUI also, it might be running in it background commands of SCP.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried already and its output.